# How to represent shared state with freezed without casting

Tags: flutter, bloc, freezed

I'm using the [freezed](https://pub.dev/packages/freezed) package to generate state objects which are consumed by the [bloc library](https://bloclibrary.dev/).

I like the ability to define union classes for a widget's state so that I can express the different and often disjoint states that a widget has.  For example:

```dart
@freezed
class ResultsReportState with _$ResultsReportState {
  const factory ResultsReportState.loading() = ResultsReportLoading;

  const factory ResultsReportState.success({
    required ReportViewViewModel report,
  }) = ResultsReportSuccess;

  const factory ResultsReportState.refreshing({
    required ReportViewViewModel report,
  }) = ResultsReportRefreshing;

  const factory ResultsReportState.error() = ResultsReportError;
}
```

In the snippet above, my intent is to not show any data when there was an error or the widget is loading, but I do still want to show data if it successfully loads or if the user is refreshing the widget.  So the `ResultsReportSuccess` and `ResultsReportRefreshing` states have a shared state which is `ReportViewViewModel`.  However, I have no ability to access those shared properties even after performing a type check [as suggested here](https://pub.dev/packages/freezed#shared-properties).

For example, this does not work without an explicit type-cast:

```dart
class ResultsReport extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocBuilder<ResultsReportBloc, ResultsReportState>(
      builder: (context, state) {
        if (state is ResultsReportSuccess || state is ResultsReportRefreshing) {
          return SliverList(
            delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
              (context, index) {
                var serviceCategory = state.report.serviceCategories[index];
                return ServiceCategoryBlock(
                  viewModel: serviceCategory,
                );
              },
              childCount: state.report.serviceCategories.length,
            ),
          );
        } else if (state is ResultsReportLoading) {
          return ResultsScreenLoadingSkeleton();
        } else {
          return SliverFillRemaining(
            child: ErrorStateContent(
              onErrorRetry: () {
                context
                    .read<ResultsReportBloc>()
                    .add(ResultsReportEvent.retryButtonTapped());
              },
            ),
          );
        }
      },
    );
  }
}
```

But there is nothing for me to explicitly type-cast to since it could be either type.  So, I tried this approach instead which introduces an interface that I can refer to:

```dart
part of 'results_report_bloc.dart';

abstract class ReportPopulated {
  ReportViewViewModel get report;
}

@freezed
class ResultsReportState with _$ResultsReportState {
  const factory ResultsReportState.loading() = ResultsReportLoading;

  @Implements<ReportPopulated>()
  const factory ResultsReportState.success({
    required ReportViewViewModel report,
  }) = ResultsReportSuccess;

  @Implements<ReportPopulated>()
  const factory ResultsReportState.refreshing({
    required ReportViewViewModel report,
  }) = ResultsReportRefreshing;

  const factory ResultsReportState.error() = ResultsReportError;
}
```

```dart
class ResultsReport extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocBuilder<ResultsReportBloc, ResultsReportState>(
      builder: (context, state) {
        if (state is ReportPopulated) {
          return SliverList(
            delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
              (context, index) {
                var serviceCategory = state.report.serviceCategories[index];
                return ServiceCategoryBlock(
                  viewModel: serviceCategory,
                );
              },
              childCount: state.report.serviceCategories.length,
            ),
          );
        } else if (state is ResultsReportLoading) {
          return ResultsScreenLoadingSkeleton();
        } else {
          return SliverFillRemaining(
            child: ErrorStateContent(
              onErrorRetry: () {
                context
                    .read<ResultsReportBloc>()
                    .add(ResultsReportEvent.retryButtonTapped());
              },
            ),
          );
        }
      },
    );
  }
}
```

But this also requires a type-cast.  So, I could do this:

```dart
class ResultsReport extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocBuilder<ResultsReportBloc, ResultsReportState>(
      builder: (context, state) {
        if (state is ReportPopulated) {
          ReportPopulated currentState = state as ReportPopulated;
          return SliverList(
            delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
              (context, index) {
                var serviceCategory = currentState.report.serviceCategories[index];
                return ServiceCategoryBlock(
                  viewModel: serviceCategory,
                );
              },
              childCount: currentState.report.serviceCategories.length,
            ),
          );
        } else if (state is ResultsReportLoading) {
          return ResultsScreenLoadingSkeleton();
        } else {
          return SliverFillRemaining(
            child: ErrorStateContent(
              onErrorRetry: () {
                context
                    .read<ResultsReportBloc>()
                    .add(ResultsReportEvent.retryButtonTapped());
              },
            ),
          );
        }
      },
    );
  }
}
```

But I'm left wondering why the type-cast is necessary, as it just feels cumbersome.  Any insight someone can provide on how to accomplish my goal of shared state differently is certainly welcomed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem you are facing could be related to Dart type promotion that does not always work as you could expect. It is thoroughly explained [here](https://github.com/dart-lang/language/blob/master/working/enhanced-type-promotion/feature-specification.md).

However, how I do handle this with `freezed` is by using the generated union methods. When rendering the UI, you could use them like this:

```
class ResultsReport extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocBuilder<ResultsReportBloc, ResultsReportState>(
      builder: (context, state) => state.maybeWhen(
        loading: () => ResultsScreenLoadingSkeleton(),
        success: (report) => SliverList(
          delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
            (context, index) {
              var serviceCategory = report.serviceCategories[index];
              return ServiceCategoryBlock(
                viewModel: serviceCategory,
              );
            },
            childCount: report.serviceCategories.length,
          ),
        ),
        refreshing: (report) => SliverList(
          delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
            (context, index) {
              var serviceCategory = report.serviceCategories[index];
              return ServiceCategoryBlock(
                viewModel: serviceCategory,
              );
            },
            childCount: report.serviceCategories.length,
          ),
        ),
        error: () => SliverFillRemaining(
          child: ErrorStateContent(
            onErrorRetry: () {
              context
                  .read<ResultsReportBloc>()
                  .add(ResultsReportEvent.retryButtonTapped());
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Notice that `success` and `refreshing` states' code is duplicated, hence you should probably extract it to a separate Widget.

Comment: After reading the mechanics of type promotion in Dart in your linked documentation, I agree that is the limitation of the language that I'm running into here.  Thank you for confirming, and thank you for the suggestion on using freezed's built-in union methods.